# How to Take MongoDB BackUp

Tags: mongodb, backup, database

I have a MongoDB Data Base Having around 50 collections..
It Contain some master collection and some transaction collections.
I want to take backup of my database every 5 hour .. PLz suggest some solution to do that

Comment: @NickMitchinson: it is  ok that u have given a link but it is not give me a optimize sol..and my question is all so very specific and important.. but why u make it down.. if u have relay some solution plz suggest..

Comment: Unfortunately you are going to have to do some of the work yourself. I can not tell you exactly how to set up a cron job on your system because I have absolutely no idea what your set up is. If you need more specific help setting up a cron job, I would post a new question asking that specifically with more information about your system. And I did not downvote your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is very likely to be closed, but I'll give you a hand anyways. Dumping a mongo database is very easy. Look at the [mongodump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodump/) command. Once you have this, set up a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to execute it when you want (in this case, every 5 hours).

For some more information on setting up cron jobs, take a look [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+set+up+a+cron+job).

Comment: What you did in "take a look [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+set+up+a+cron+job)"? linked to a google search query `search?q=how+to+set+up+a+cron+job`? You could have told him to do a search.

Comment: While I do understand that, I had honestly already typed the sentence, went to find a link to post, but then figured that due to system differences a specific link may not have been as helpful as I had originally thought. Giving him that link gave a variety of articles and to be fair saved him/her a step. I get that it could have come across as a bit... rude? maybe, but it's still a few steps nicer than a lmgtfy link.